# Apache mod_proxy not mapping incoming port to local IP address

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy

I'm trying to allow another device on the same network to access an app running on my local machine within a VM. The local IP of the app within the VM is accessable at http://192.168.10.10/

If I load this IP in the browser of my local machine I can see the homepage, good. Ofcourse remote devices will not know this IP address as it's local. So I'm trying to use mod_proxy to allow external devices to see the homepage on a given port number.

I've enable mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http:

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
```

..and restarted apache to ensure that modules are available.

Here is my apache conf file /etc/apache2/sites-available/rev.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:8088>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass        "/" "http://192.168.10.10/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://192.168.10.10/"
    ServerName hostname.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

It's very basic. In fact, I just lifted it from https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/vhosts/examples.html. I've `a2ensite rev.conf` and reloaded apache. It was giving me errors on the ProxyPass* lines before I'd enable the modules, but now apache reloads without any errors.

I'm using `ifconfig` to determine what the local IP is on the network for other devices, but when I try the IP with port number (e.g. 192.168.1.2:8088) from another device it just tells me:

> Unable to connect
>
> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 192.168.1.2:8088.
>
> ```
> The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
> If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
> If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
> ```

... as though I'd mis-typed a URL so I'm guessing. Seems the proxy isn't working then.

Even on the local machine if I try `http://localhost:8088` it doesn't load. So something wrong with my apache conf file?

Comment: What kind of error is it showing? Time out? Connection refused? Or some other error? Do you have a firewall enabled?

Comment: I've updated my post to quote the error when I try to connect by IP address and port. I'm not even able to connect using localhost:8088 which I was expecting to from the server machine. I can definitely see my website at http://192.168.10.10.

Comment: I assume that error message means a timeout. What happens if you remove `ServerName hostname.example.com`? This seems to only respond to that domain.

Comment: It's no different